# Creating formula for distance and damage

Tags: java, formula, distance

```
    public double getDamage(double distance){
        int damage1 = 30; // (0 - 38.1)
        int damage2 = 20; // (50.8 - *)
        double range1 = 38.1;
        double range2 = 50.8;

        double damage = 0; // FORMULA

        return damage;
    }
```

I try to create a formula to calculate the amount of damage that has been effected by the distance.

(Variable Distance =)
0 till 38.1 metre It will return 30 damage.
50.8 till Inifite it will return 20 damage.
38.1 till 50.8 it will decrease linear 30 -> 20.

How can I make this method work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this:

```
double x = (distance - range1) / (range2 - range1);
if (x < 0)
  x = 0;
if (x > 1)
  x = 1;
return damage1 + x * (damage2 - damage1);
```

Basically you follow a linear rule and also adjust to stay in your linear interval.

Comment: Thanks this is dynamic and exactly what I needed! It might has an easy answer, but I kept getting stuck. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a step formula, not a linear formula. Step formula is basically a bunch of if-else if comparisons in code. Something like this:

```
public double getDamage(double dist){
    if (0 < dist & dist < 38.1)
        return 30;
    else if ( 38.1 < dist & dist < 50.8 )
        return 30 - dist/10;
    else 
        return 

}
```

Edit: just saw you do want it linearly between 38.1 and 50.8.
Use something like this return 30 - dist/10; dist/10 would give you damage of 27 to 23, you'd need to find an appropriate constant (instead of 10) yourself. (Which is easy since its y = mx + b and you have two points by your conditions (38.1, 30) and (50.8, 20). So sub those into y = mx+b and you'll get the formula to use in the 2nd else-if.

Comment: For the 0-38.1 and 50.8 I can use a if-else ladder.
But for the 38.1 -> 50.8 It needs a formula to calculate the damage on for instance 42.5 (What should give around 24damage+/-)

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are looking for is a simple variation of the point-slop equation y = m(x-x1) + y1 equation, where m = (damage1 - damage2)/(range1 - range2), x1 = range1, y1 = damage1, and x is the variable distance.

```
public double getDamage(double distance){
    int damage1 = 30;
    int damage2 = 20;
    double range1 = 38.1;
    double range2 = 50.8;

    double damage = 0;
    if(0 <= distance && distance <= range1)
        damage = damage1;
    else if (range1 < distance && distance < range2)
        damage = (damage1 - damage2)/(range1 - range2) * (distance - range1) + damage1;
    else if (distance >= range2)
        damage = damage2;

    return damage;
}
```